# is it wrong/dangerous to include aws-exports.js file in source control?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

amplify auto-ignores `aws-exports.js` in `.gitignore` possibly simply because it may change frequently and is fully generated - however maybe there are also security concerns?

For this project my github project is private so that is not a concern, but I am wondering for future projects that could be public.

The reason I ask is because if I want to run my app setup/build/test through github workflows then I need this file for the build to complete properly on github machines?

Also I appear to need it for my amplify CI hosting to work on amplify console (I have connected my amplify console build->deploy to my github master branch and it all works perfectly but only when aws-exports.js is in source control).

Here is my `amplify.yml`, I am using reason-react with nextjs, and my amplify console is telling me I have connected to the correct backend:

```
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - yarn install
    build:
      commands:
        - yarn run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: out
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

Comment: The aws-exports is generated when you pull/checkout an environment, no need to version it

Comment: @danielfranca thanks, I'm asking about what to do in environments where you cannot do (or it is difficult to do) amplify pull, e.g. github-workflows?  To clarify further it is much easier to source control the aws-exports and push to github and then have the workflow run as expected than to set up the github workflow environment and aws in such a way that you can use amplify cli.  So given this easy workaround I am asking if there are further concerns like security